# How can I change VSCode's default terminal

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I am a big fan of VSCode for how customizeable it is, but one thing really bugs me. I write code in Java, and for whatever reason scanners don't work with VSCode's default terminal, the internal console. It isn't a big deal, and I can fix it by just going into launch.json and changing the "console" option from internal console to integrated terminal, but it is annoying to do because one, I have to do it every time, and two, I have to run my Java file and watch it crash before the launch.json file even shows up.

TLDR: Is there some way to change the default so that it ALWAYS launches .java files in the integrated terminal instead of the internal console? I have looked around the settings multiple times and haven't found anything promising.

To be clear, I am not trying to change my default shell. I don't want to go from the standard prompt to powershell or bash or anything like that. I want to change the way it launches my programs.

Comment: `I have to run my Java file and watch it crash before the launch.json file even shows up` : Do you mean, every time you start a new java project, you have to run it once to make `launch.json` to be generated?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I mean

Comment: You don't have to, every time you start a new project and open it in vscode, wait for the Java Language server to start, then you can create a new `launch.json` by following guide in this link : https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging